# Does janus grid control have group by event?

Tags: .net, janus, gridex

how to make invisible group by column visible when user drags group by column back to the grid?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are GroupsChanged and GroupsChanging events on the grid you can hook into.

These events only fire when a user interacts with the grid visually, they do not fire when you change the groups via code.

The GroupsChangingEventArgs provided by the GroupsChanging event, specifically the Action property will tell you what change is being performed on the Groups (Add, Move, Remove, SortOrderChanged).

Based on the Action you can make a choice about the Visibiliy of the GridEXColumn.

The GroupsChangingEventArgs.Group.GridEXColumnproperty will tell you which GridEXColumn is being impacted.